# Accessing resource file when running as a DataflowPipelineRunner in Google Dataflow

Tags: java, google-cloud-dataflow

In my project, I am trying to add some metadata to the data processed in my pipeline. The metadata is located in a DBF file in a subfolder called resources next the src-folder.

The src-folder contains the main-class and I have several packages (IO, processing, aggregation, utils).

I read and process the file with metadata in my main class where the pipeline is defined. The code I am using to access the file is as follows:

```
File temp1 = new File("resources/xxx.dbf");
```

I check if the file was found using:

```
LOG.info(temp1.exists())
```

which runs fine.

There are messages coming in as Strings which I read using PubSubIO. I use the contents of this file to fill a Map containing keys and values.

```
Map<String, ArrayList<Double>> sensorToCoordinates = coordinateData.getSensorLocations();
```

I then set a static variable in a custom class called 'SensorValues' I made:

```
SensorValue.setKeyToCoordinates(sensorToCoordinates);
```

When parsing the incoming messages from Strings to a SensorValue-class I made using a ParDo function (going from a PCollection to PCollection) the map is used in the constructor of the SensorValue-class.

Running this code using a DirectPipelineRunner works perfect. However, when I use a DataflowPipelineRunner, and I try to access the map in the SensorValue-constructor, I run into a NullPointerException.

Now I am wondering why the setter is not working when using a DataflowPipelineRunner (I'm guessing it has something to do with the execution being distributed among several workers) and what the best practice would be to use any static resource files to enrich your pipeline with?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're right that the problem is because the execution of the `ParDo` is distributed to multiple workers. They don't have the local file, and they may don't have the contents of the map.

There are a few options here:

1. Put the file in GCS, and have the pipeline read the contents of the file (using TextIO or something like that) and use it as a [side-input](https://cloud.google.com/dataflow/model/par-do#side-inputs) to your later processing.
2. Include the file in the resources for the pipeline and load that in the `startBundle` of the `DoFn` that needs it (in the future there will be ways to make this happen less often than every bundle).
3. You could serialize the contents of the map into the arguments of the `DoFn`, by putting it in as a non-static field passed to the constructor of that class.

Option 1 is better as the size of this file increases (since it can support splitting it up to pieces and doing lookups) while Option 2 is likely less network traffic to retrieve the file. Option 3 will only work if the file is extremely small, since it will significantly increase the size of the serialized `DoFn`, which may lead to the job being to large to submit to the Dataflow service.

Comment: I tried the first solution and it works.

I used a `PCollectionView<Map<String, double[]>>` to map the keys to the right coordinates (with View.asMap()), works like a charm, thanks Ben!